# Why is array initialization in a static context?

Tags: c#

Let's consider this class:

```
class ABClass
{
    object a;
    object b;

    object[] ab = new[] {a, b};
}
```

This does not compile :

```
A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'TestConsole.ABClass.a'
A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'TestConsole.ABClass.b'
```

However, R# suggest this to fix successfully the compilation:

```
class ABClass
{
    object a;
    object b;

    object[] ab;

    public ABClass()
    {
        ab = new[] {a, b};
    }
}
```

Why does the array initialization seem to happen in a static context?

Follow-up : in C# 6 there is the [auto-properties with initializers](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/08/04/c-6-0-features-part-i-property-initializers.aspx) feature. How will it relate to my issue?

Comment: Depending on field initialization order causes *way* too many accidents.  The language simply outlawed it to prevent programmers from shooting their leg off, the workaround is trivial.

Comment: Note that `a` and `b` have their default values at the time you create that array, so you could use `new[] { (object)null, null }` or `new object[] { null, null }` or just `new object[2]` instead, and that would be more clear. The entries in the array are not "by ref", so assigning other references to `a` and `b` at a later time will not affect the array instance.

Comment: To see that this is not related to arrays, try the example `class A2Class { object a; object a2 = a /* error */; }`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've asked: `**Why** does the array initialization **seem to happen** in a static context?`.

Instead of pointing you to the specs of the language (which simply and clearly say "you cant do that, period"), let's think about the cause.

It happens in static context, because the otherwise, it would use a half-constructed object instance. The fields `a, b` might be, or might be not initialized. They may be accessible from the constructor, or base constructor, or derived constructore, from base/derived methods, those methods might be called via virtual/override from this or base constructors, etc.

If the fields' initializers were allowed to read/refer to other instance fields and/or to call instance methods, there is no way the compiler could guess the correct order of initialization of fields.

Moreover, note that field initialization process executes before the constructor. Allowing the fields to access instance fields/props/methods would mean that those methods could be called before the constructor (and base constructors) are called, which would lead to manystrange and counterintuitive effects.

So, the language was designed in a way to prevent it. The initializers are simply designed/forced to execute in static context, so you won't be tempted to rely on the half-constructed object instance capabilities, and also so you will not clutter the code too much. This way, you will not accidentally forget about the dangers. You can still do all of that in the constructor, but there you always know that "its the constructor" and naturally you are a bit more cautious. Of course, you can still shoot yourself in the foot with calling virtual methods from the ctor, but well, tracing and debugging that is far easier, as in the constructor's code at least the **order of execution** of lines is obvious, while for initializer it could be not so.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because the Specs say so:

> A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or
>   property

Your fields `a` and `b` are non-static. You can't access them in object initializer. That is why you need a constructor.

As for C# 6 auto properties initializers:

This is not related to your code, you don't have any auto implemented property.

Comment: Alright. As for the C# 6 question, I was implying "what if I change my variable into an auto property and initialize the auto property the same way I initialized the variable?"

Comment: @Max, in that case the error would remain same, I imagine you want something like `public object[] ab { get; set; } = new[] { a, b };` where `a` and `b` are both defined as properties or fields. It will still throw the same error, since you can't access non-static field, method and **property**.

Answer (score 0):

From the MSDN "A variable initializer for an instance field cannot reference the instance being created."

here is the link that was derived from: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645759(v=vs.71).aspx

further reading on instance constructors: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645602(v=vs.71).aspx